# Using global $post; to get featured image for custom post via WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-thumbnails, globals

I'm using a site-wide function to add css to the `<head>` of the page pull in featured images of various as a responsive page background. It works great across the rest of my site but fails on a page where I'm calling posts from a custom post type using `WP_Query`. I think this is because `WP_Query` doesn't use the standard loop, and my function uses `global $post;`.

Is there a way to adapt the `WP_Query` loop to work with the function? I need the featured image function to also work on the rest of my site, which uses the standard WP loop.

--

Here's how I'm calling the custom posts:

```
<?php $port_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
) ); 
if ( $port_query->have_posts() ): while ( $port_query->have_posts() ) : $port_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="page-bkg responsive-bkg">
        // page content here
    </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;
```

And the function to call responsive featured images, from functions.php:

```
function bkg_featured_image() {

// call the global post variable
global $post;

if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) : // checks whether the post has the featured image set

// get the post thumbnail ID for the page or post
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

// store the image sizes in an array. You can also add your own image sizes with the add_image_size function
$img_sizes = array( 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full', 'thumb480', 'thumb768', 'thumb1280', 'thumb1680', 'thumb2048' );

// grab the URL for each image size and store in a variable
foreach ( $img_sizes as $img_size ) {
    ${ 'img_src_' . $img_size } = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $img_size );
}

echo '<style type="text/css"> 

    .responsive-bkg {
        background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_thumb768[0] ) . ');
    }

    @media screen and ( min-width: 768px ) {
        .responsive-bkg {
            background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_thumb1280[0] ) . ');
        }
    }

    @media screen and ( min-width: 1281px ) {
        .responsive-bkg {
            background-image: url(' . esc_url( $img_src_thumb2048[0] ) . ');
        }
    }

</style>';

   endif; // end if the featured image is set

} // end function my_featured_image

add_action( 'wp_head', 'bkg_featured_image' );

// (this function borrowed from http://s2webpress.com/responsive-featured-image-function-in-wordpress-themes/)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$port_query->the_post();` should set the `$post` `global`. That isn't the problem. The problem is that the you are trying to use `$post` before your secondary Loop runs (99% sure).

You've hooked the `bkg_featured_image()` function to `wp_head`. `wp_head` runs in the header of the document, which, unless you are careful, will run before the other template code.

If you think about how WordPress theme template loading works, you will realize that `get_header()` loads `header.php` which should be where the header hooks fire. That means that code before `get_header()` in a theme file can use those hooks successfully.

The fix is to make sure your secondary loop runs before `get_header()`. `$post` should be set to the first post in those results and your code should work. That doesn't mean you have to output the results before `get_header()`, which wouldn't make sense. You just have to run the query.

Of course, you only have the *first* post in the Loop by doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How would I set `$post` to the first post in the results, as you suggest?

Comment: `WP_Query` will populate `$post` with the first post in the Loop. It does that by default.

Comment: I can successfully get all information from a post to display with the code I've used above, except for the featured image, so it seems you are right.

Comment: You need to be very carefull with this as it exploits what may not be intended behavior.

Comment: To clarify, I can load the featured image on the page using `the_post_thumbnail()` but the function above does not load it as a background image.

Comment: What do you mean @s_ha_dum?

Comment: Setting `$post` before the Loop starts has always struck me as odd.

Comment: Is there a way to run this outside of `wp_head` and still have it in functions.php? I'd like to ensure the CSS is placed in the `<head>` of the page.

Answer (score 0):

WP_Query does use $post. A full list of Methods and Properties can be found [In the codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties). Are you sure that all your Portfolio items have featured images? you might want to use `'meta_key'    => '_thumbnail_id',` in the arg to make sure the random Portfolio has an image. you could also check in the template using

```
if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) :

    <div class="page-bkg responsive-bkg">
    // page content here
</div>

endif;
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, every post on the whole website has a featured image – it's a photographer's website!